# What's wrong with this way to add rows to dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
data <- data.frame(A= character(0), B= character(0))
data[1, ] <- c("AA", "BB")


Warning messages:

1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "AA") :

  invalid factor level, NA generated

2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "BB") :

  invalid factor level, NA generated
> data
     A    B
 1   NA NA
```

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data <- data.frame(A= character(0), B= character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data[1, ] <- c("AA", "BB")
```

In your example, `A` and `B` are factors.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach from the other answers.  If A and B are something like names or ID numbers that will be unique then treating them as strings is fine and the other answers are fine.  But if A and B are categorical variables that you will turn into factors (either yourself or by automatic conversion when passed to a function needing factors) then there are advantages to creating the factors up front and specifying the levels to begin with.

```
> mydata <- data.frame( A=factor(levels=c('A','AA','AAA')), 
+ B=factor(levels=c('BB','CC','DD')) )
> mydata[1,] <- c('AA','BB')
> mydata[2,] <- c('A','bb')
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "bb") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> mydata
   A    B
1 AA   BB
2  A <NA>
>
```

See, if you set the columns as factors and set up the valid levels to begin with, then adding in a correct row does the correct thing, but if you make a typo in entering a row then you receive the helpful warning message letting you know that you did something wrong and to fix it up front rather than waiting to be stung by it at analysis time.  This also lets you specify the ordering of the factor levels instead of using the default alphabetical ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you started with default `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` (it is safer to start with 'stringsAsFactors=FALSE')

```
 data <- data.frame(A= factor(character(0),levels=c("AA","AA2")), B= factor(character(0),levels=c("BB","BB2")))
 data
 #[1] A B
 #<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
data[1,] <- c("AA","BB")
data
#  A  B
#1 AA BB
data[2:3,] <- c("AA","AA2","BB","BB2")
data
#   A   B
# 1  AA  BB
# 2  AA  BB
# 3 AA2 BB2
```